# Alarm Manager doesn't fire any alarm on flyme os (meizu)

Tags: android, alarmmanager

First of all alarms fires well on other devices. *Problem is exactly in FlymeOS* (it's battery optimization, security features or something like that).

Second I've tried different alarms `setRepeating(), setExact(), setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` with understanding difference between them. Result - again works well everywhere except meizu devices.

So how can I make these alarms fire on meizu?

Comment: my meizu device run by android 5.1

Comment: it's flyme 6 I guess?

Comment: exactly - 6.2 G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in background processes restrictions on meizu. There are 3 running in background modes: *"Allow running in background"*, *"Smart background"* (this is the root of your problem) and *"Disallow running in background"*. So **second is set for every app by default** and so alarm will fire only is app launched right now, otherwise not.

To fix your problem **"Allow running in background" should be set**. But you can not do it programmatically, so *user should change this setting himself*.
All you can do is to open meizu security page for your application and call user to change this setting to *"Allow running in background"*:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.meizu.safe.security.SHOW_APPSEC");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.putExtra("packageName", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
```

[image: Running in background mode menu]

Comment: Thanks! Works on Meizu m5c

Comment: When the security page is opened, I can't figure out how to get this dialog to choose "Allow running in background" like on screenshot above. Should I add some permition to Manifest?

Comment: Unfortunately you can not open this dialog programmatically. The only thing you can do is to instruct user open this dialog manually and choose "Allow running in background" and provide button opening this security page for him.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I understand that user has to open this dialog himself. My question is: being on the security page what exact button should user tap to make this dialog appear? For example, on my phone (Meizu M5 - Flyme 5.2.10) I see only this list of permissions: http://funkyimg.com/i/2NPFY.jpg. Maybe I need to add some extra permission I don't know?